# close, dispose, finalize, GC, Idisposable,.... have you got a clear description of them?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable, finalize

i am completely confused about close, dispose, finalize, GC, Idisposable.
Oh, could you please send me a clear description of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a fairly large topic. May I recommend the book [CLR via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/6522.aspx) by Richter. It goes into details about all the issues you mention.

A very brief translation:

- On disposable types Close is often the same as Dispose.
- Dispose is used to allow deterministic clean up of resources not handled by garbage collection.
- Finalizer (or destructor as the C# language spec calls it) is a clean-up method called by the garbage collection code at some point in time. I.e. unlike destructors for C++ this is not done at a well defined point in time.
- GC is short for garbage collection and refers to .NET's automatic clean-up of objects located on the managed heap.
- IDisposable is an interface, that states that the type in question implements the Dispose method as outlined above.

For more details please consult the book. [This rather elaborate blog entry](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/04/08/dg-update-dispose-finalization-and-resource-management/) by Joe Duffy is also very useful for understanding IDisposable and finalizers.

Comment: Thanks Brian, when should we implement a finalize method for a class?
Or Is that really necessary to implement it?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to Joe Duffy's excellent treatment of that question, so please see that. The short answer is: You shoud rarely finalizers. If your classes only uses managed resources you most likely will not need finalizers.

Comment: The link to joe's blog nolonger points to the post. can you update it?